# How to get and modify a property value through a custom Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a custom attribute that can be used on a property like:

```
[TrimInputString]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

that will be functional equivalent of

```
private string _firstName
public string FirstName {
  set {
    _firstName = value.Trim();
  }
  get {
    return _firstName;
  }
}
```

So basically every time property is set the value will be trimmed.

How do I get the value parsed, modify that value and then set the property with the new value all from within the attribute?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TrimInputAttribute : Attribute {

  public TrimInputAttribute() {
    //not sure how to get and modify the property here
  }

}
```

Comment: I think a better approach is a DataBinder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1734025/7720

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not how attributes work. You can't access whatever the attribute is attached to from within the constructor.

If you want to make this work, you'll need to make some kind of processor class to which you pass the object, which then goes through the fields and does something depending on the attributes. The operation to do may be defined within the attribute (an abstract base attribute is handy here), but you'll still need to go through the fields by hand to apply the operation.

Answer (score 26):

iam doing this , not very convincing way but its working

**demo class**

```
public class User
{

[TitleCase]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[TitleCase]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[UpperCase]
public string Salutation { get; set; }

[LowerCase]
public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

**Writing Attribute for LowerCase**, others can be written in the similar manner

```
public class LowerCaseAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       //try to modify text
            try
            {
                validationContext
                .ObjectType
                .GetProperty(validationContext.MemberName)
                .SetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, value.ToString().ToLower(), null);
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {                                    
            }

        //return null to make sure this attribute never say iam invalid
        return null;
    }
}
```

Not very elegant way as its actually implementing Validation attribute but it works

Comment: This, of course, only works if your program at some point runs validation on the objects. Interesting hack, but I wouldn't use it in production code.

Comment: Maybe you would want to `return ValidationResult.Success;`

Answer (score 1):

As Matti pointed out, this is not how attributes work. However, you could use the [PostSharp AOP framework](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/download) to accomplish this, probably overriding OnMethodBoundaryAspect. But this is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [Dado.ComponentModel.Mutations](https://github.com/roydukkey/Dado.ComponentModel.Mutations).

```
public class User
{
    [Trim]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

// Then to preform mutation
var user = new User() {
    FirstName = " David Glenn   "
}

new MutationContext<User>(user).Mutate();
```

You can see more documentation [here](https://github.com/roydukkey/Dado.ComponentModel.Mutations/tree/master/Documentation).

Comment: Not judging about the solution itself. But the chosen namespace I find misleading. My first impression is that it is part of the .Net framework itself. While it is not. Why not start the namespace with RoyDukkey.ComponentModel.Mutations and give credit to your name as well.

Comment: I agree. This was originally built as a proposal, but has since been closed. I've yet the time to change the namespace to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem
you should use JsonSeralizer attributes
it will works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).