# Blanks converts to null in razor view C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have model with a property of `string` type. I bind this model to view (razor view) and bind this property to hidden field. The property has value as blank (`String.Empty`).

When I post model to controller, the value what I get is null instead of blank.

Any idea?

Comment: The cause is a bit complicated. Just to simplify it if I have a string (say strSomething) with value "" and I do strSomething.ToString() it will work but if the string will have value null, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to preserve null values as nulls and empty strings as empty strings for a round-trip operation, perhaps you could define a special constant string value to denote null.
Perhaps something like this in a static class (so you can make an extension of it):

```
private const string NULL_STRING = "__@NULL@__";

public static string StringifyIfNull(this string s) {
  return s == null ? NULL_STRING : s;
}

public static string DestringifyIfNull(this string s) {
  return NULL_STRING == s ? null : s;
}
```

So, when setting the hidden string properties on your model, use `hiddenString.StringifyIfNull()`, and when reading back the hidden values after a POST, use `model.HiddenString.DestringifyIfNull()`

Comment: It worked. I just had to change the condition. 
To Stringify, return s == ""? NULL_STRING : s;

To Destringify, return s == NULL_STRING? "" : s;

Answer (score 4):

Add [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)] to your class markup.

Answer (score 1):

That is what the MVC framework does when it maps request data to controller parameters, and the request data is an empty value. If you check the value in the `Request.Form` collection, you will see that it actually is an empty string there, not a null value.

You can either handle the null values that the framework generates, or read the data from the `Request.Form` collection.

Answer (score 0):

This link should be helpful.

[Why do I get null instead of empty string when receiving POST request in from Razor View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641723/asp-net-mvc-why-do-i-get-null-instead-of-empty-string-when-receiving-post-reque)

"The default model binding will create a new SomeModel for you. The default value for the string type is null since it's a reference type, so it's being set to null." Original answer by statichippo