# Allow empty strings for fields marked with PhoneAttribute or UrlAttribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I'm using CodeFirst Entitty framework 5. I have a class representing a user.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Url]
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings= true)]
    public string WebSite { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}
```

I like the validation mechanics for `Phone` and `Url` attributes a lot, but unfortunately validation fails when fields marked with these attributes are empty strings which I actually want to allow. `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]` doesn't seem to work with `Phone` or `Url` attributes. The same seems to apply to some other DataAnnotations attributes like `EmailAddress`.

Is there a way to allow empty strings for fields marked with such attributes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Validation attributes like `[Phone]` and `[EmailAddress]` will check any non-null string values. Because the `string` type is inherently nullable, empty strings passed to the ModelBinder are read as `null`, which passes the validation check.

When you add the  `[Required]` attribute, the string becomes effectively non-nullable.  (If using Code First, EF will script a non-nullable database column.) The ModelBinder will now interpret a blank value as `String.Empty` - which will fail the attribute validation check.

So there is no way to allow *empty* strings with validation attributes, but you can allow *null* strings.  All you need to do is remove the `[Required]` attribute. Blank values will be `null` and non-blank values will be validated.

In my case, I am importing records from a CSV file, and had this problem because I was skipping the normal ModelBinder.  If you are doing something unusual like this, be sure to include a manual check before saving to your data model:

```
Email = (record.Email == String.Empty) ? null : record.Email
```

Comment: I wasn't using Model Binder. I was writing data importer and the source data contains empty emails and phones. I guess I should just convert empty strings from source to nulls then. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @Nu-hin.  Your DBA will thank you in the future if you get in a habbit of cleaning up ambiguous pointless values like empty strings and replacing them with null.  Null is undefined or unknown.  A empty string phone number is undefined or unknown.  Always fun to do work on a db years later and find a mix of null, empty strings, whitespace strings, and the always helpful "NO PHONE NUMBER" in the phone number field.

Comment: This seems pretty unhelpful. Yes in *some* situations, the absence of a value means "not known", but "Definitely empty" means something quite different from "Not known". So there are cases where a empty string is not a "pointless value".

Comment: This did not work for me with the DomainAttribute but did work with the EmailAddressAttribute!

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute` as empty strings are failing validation, even though the field is not required

Comment: @MordZuber Interesting.  Two options: either `EmailAddressAttribute` has been updated to validate `null` strings or the ModelBinder is setting your blank incoming value to `string.Empty` instead of `null`.  Can you remove the validation and check the actual value set by ModelBinder?

Comment: My case was string.Empty being sent over the wire. Since the validator only checks for null, it was failing, so I just wrote a new wrapper attribute

Comment: `EmailAddressAttribute` definitely still passes null values. 
 https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs  I wonder why it was setting it to empty?

Comment: Good reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641723/why-do-i-get-null-instead-of-empty-string-when-receiving-post-request-in-from-ra

Answer (score 45):

Use following two data annotations:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
```

Comment: Works very well but I wonder why visual has generated in my case [Required][StringLength(10)] if I have not null, nvarchar(10)

Comment: Removing this "[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]" has worked for me. Thank you

Comment: Works for me on Core. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Works on Core API 3.1 also.

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar below.

```
  [JsonProperty("phone")]
  [NullablePhone]
  public string Phone { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Validation attribute for phone numbers.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="ValidationAttribute" />
public class NullablePhoneAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if phone is empty or valid.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the object to validate.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///   <see langword="true" /> if the specified value is valid; otherwise, <see langword="false" />.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        PhoneAttribute phone = new PhoneAttribute();
        return phone.IsValid(value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way I could have made this work was to take source code of .Net and adjusted it myself to allow nullable values for email attribute.

Code can be found here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class NullableEmailAddressAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{

    // This attribute provides server-side email validation equivalent to jquery validate,
    // and therefore shares the same regular expression.  See unit tests for examples.
    private static Regex _regex = CreateRegEx();

    public NullableEmailAddressAttribute()
        : base(DataType.EmailAddress)
    {

        // DevDiv 468241: set DefaultErrorMessage not ErrorMessage, allowing user to set
        // ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName to use localized messages.
        // DefaultErrorMessage = DataAnnotationsResources.EmailAddressAttribute_Invalid;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return true;

        string valueAsString = value as string;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueAsString))
            return true;

        // Use RegEx implementation if it has been created, otherwise use a non RegEx version.
        if (_regex != null)
        {
            return valueAsString != null && _regex.Match(valueAsString).Length > 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int atCount = 0;

            foreach (char c in valueAsString)
            {
                if (c == '@')
                {
                    atCount++;
                }
            }

            return (valueAsString != null
            && atCount == 1
            && valueAsString[0] != '@'
            && valueAsString[valueAsString.Length - 1] != '@');
        }
    }

    private static Regex CreateRegEx()
    {
        // We only need to create the RegEx if this switch is enabled.
        //if (AppSettings.DisableRegEx)
        //{
        //    return null;
        //}

        const string pattern = @"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$";
        const RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture;

        // Set explicit regex match timeout, sufficient enough for email parsing
        // Unless the global REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT is already set
        TimeSpan matchTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        try
        {
            if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("REGEX_DEFAULT_MATCH_TIMEOUT") == null)
            {
                return new Regex(pattern, options, matchTimeout);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Fallback on error
        }

        // Legacy fallback (without explicit match timeout)
        return new Regex(pattern, options);
    }
}
```

Usage is like so:

```
    [NullableEmailAddress]
    public string DigitalInvoiceEmail { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just come accros this very issue in .NET 6 and realized that - when nullable reference types are enabled - the builtin phone attribute causes validation to fail when the textbox is empty.
In order to allow empty value & null for the phone attribute in that case, simply mark the string property for the phone number as nullable.

```cs
[Display(Name = "Business phone (optional)")]
public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

or dissable nullable reference type handling for the page model class by prepending

```cs
#nullable disable
```