# MVC Validation for Non-Nullable String

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a very simple Model with an ID(int) and 4 Non-Null String fields.  They can be empty though.  If I put [Required] on them it forces a Value to be entered.  If I don't do anything and you leave it blank it throws an error as by default Blank==null.

How do I get it to default to String.Empty?

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475273/how-to-convert-textboxes-with-null-values-to-empty-strings) or at the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383696/asp-net-mvc-converting-null-to-zero-length-string)