# asp.net mvc trim string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to trim a string in asp.net mvc . i will be doing that in controller where there is a updatemodel implemented or datannotation class or a view? where will be i doing that?

Comment: i have a textboxes bind to the model , i want to trim any string inside the textboxes. i am using linq to sql with asp.net mvc 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want trim strings that Users have entered then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custom)

Although this answer only overrides the SetProperty method you could always extend the class and add a method to override the `GetPropertyValue`

Comment: As Barry has said, take a look at that answer. I also implemented a my own ModelBinder that automatically trimmed strings. Much better.