# Where to Trim() incoming request parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, trim

I have the following block of code

```
public ActionResult Tabs(SearchViewModel svm)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        svm.Summary = _entitySearchService.GetSearchDataSummary(svm.Search);
        return PartialView(svm);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("QuickSearch", "Search"
            , new RouteValueDictionary { { "search",  svm.Search } });
    }
}
```

if the user submits a search that ends with a space, e.g. "something ", it works fine if it's an ajax request, but if it's not an ajax request, the request gets redirected to a different Action Method, at which point something goes wrong and a 404 is returned.

I could do a `trim()` in the `else` clause, e.g.

`new RouteValueDictionary { { "search",  svm.Search.Trim() } }`

but there are a few places that this happens. Ideally I could do it all in the one place.

Would it be considered too hackish if I put it into the Controller's `Initialize` method?

```
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        // do a test to see if there's a 'search' parameter in requestContext,
        // and if so, trim it

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

Or is there another better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the setter of your SearchViewModel if this is an option

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
   ...

   private string search;

   public string Search
   {
      get
      {
         return search;
      }
      set
      {
         search = value.Trim();
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[ASP.NET MVC: Best way to trim strings after data entry.  Should I create a custom model binder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custom/1734025#1734025)