# Affecting MVC ModelBinders with Attributes

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, modelbinders

In MVC3 (.Net) it is possible to set a Bind Attribute on a parameter Type in the method signature for a Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = "Name")]User user)
{
   ...
}
```

I have written some Custom ModelBinders. It would be nice to be able to affect their behavior based on attributes set on a parameter Type, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([CustomModelBinderSettings(DoCustomThing = "True")]User user)
{
   ...
}
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to recover the attribute data.  Is this possible?

---

**Edit**

I am trying to access the AttributeData from within a custom ModelBinder. In the example below "settings" is always null

```
public class TestBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
        public override object BindModel(
            ControllerContext controllerContext, 
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

            //Try and get attribute from ModelType
            var settings = (CustomModelBinderSettingsAttribute) 
                TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(bindingContext.ModelType)[typeof(CustomModelBinderSettingsAttribute)];

            ...
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See here:

[Finding custom attributes on view model properties][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205176/finding-custom-attributes-on-view-model-properties-when-model-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: *not possible :(*

I stepped through the MVC source code, and eventually found that the ControllorActionInvoker class explicitly accesses the bind attribute from the Action Method parameters, and sets them on a property of the bindingContext.  Without overriding or rewriting large parts of the MVC infrastructure, it is not possible for attributes added to Action Parameters to be accessed from a ModelBinder.

However, it is possible to retrieve attributes set on a *ViewModel* using the code illustrated  in LukLeds post:

```
var attr = ("GetTypeDescriptor(controllerContext, bindingContext).GetAttributes()[typeof(BindAttribute)];
```

Alas, that is not what I set out to do in this case, but it will have to do for now.

Comment: Not true, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything more than you've done to get access to the value of the DoCustomThing property from within your CustomModelBinderAttribute.  Where are you trying to read the value of DoCustomThing that it's not available?

```
public class CustomModelBinderSettingsAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public string DoCustomThing { get; set; }
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        // Pass the value of DoCustomThing to the custom model binder instance.
        MyCustomizableModelBinder binder = new MyCustomizableModelBinder(this.DoCustomThing);
        return binder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have updated my question to include an example of the context I am trying to access the attribute data from

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you have (or create new) AuthorizeAttribute (filter attribute), that will store filterContext.ActionDescriptor (your action) in HttpContext.Current.Items and later in ModelBinder that value will be retrieved. Having ActionDescriptor you can find desired parameter by bindingContext.ModelName and check for attribute presence.

Things to note:

- ModelBinder is not bound to Action executed
- using ControllerContext you can get ActionName called, but not actual method called (may have multiple overloads with your parameter)
- AuthorizeFilter is called before ModelBinder, normal ActionFilter is called after ModelBinder

Answer (score 0):

You can get both the action's and its parameters' attributes by "intercepting" `Controller.ActionInvoker.FindAction()` and storing the attributes in `HttpContext.Current.Items` as mentioned here, or extended `ControllerContext.RequestContext`, as follows:

```cs
public class MyControllerActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        var action = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);

        if (action != null)
        {
            var requestContext = ExtendedRequestContext.Bind(controllerContext);

            // if necessary, use action.GetCustomAttributes() to add action's attributes

            foreach (var parameter in action.GetParameters())
            {
                var attr = parameter.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyBinderAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
                if (attr != null)
                    requestContext.Attributes.Add(parameter.ParameterName, (MyBinderAttribute)attr);
            }
        }

        return action;
    }
}

public class ExtendedRequestContext : RequestContext
{
    public Dictionary<string, MyBinderAttribute> Attributes { get; private set; }

    public static ExtendedRequestContext Bind(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var requestContext = new ExtendedRequestContext
        {
            HttpContext = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext,
            RouteData = controllerContext.RequestContext.RouteData,
            Attributes = new Dictionary<string, MyBinderAttribute>()
        };

        controllerContext.RequestContext = requestContext;
        return requestContext;
    }
}
```

The default action invoker is replaced either in your controller's constructor or in a custom controllers factory:

```cs
public MyController() : base()
{
    ActionInvoker = new MyControllerActionInvoker();
}
```

By the way, `Controller.TempData` already contains an item of `ReflectedParameterDescriptor` type, which gives you access to `ActionDescriptor`, so the above code may be redundant. However, beware this is implementation specific, so may change over time.

Finally, get the attributes from that storage in your binder class:

```cs
var requestContext = (ExtendedRequestContext)controllerContext.RequestContext;

if (requestContext.Attributes.ContainsKey(bindingContext.ModelName))
{
    var attr = requestContext.Attributes[bindingContext.ModelName];
    // apply your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here with the same question but for .net core. I have not checked if this applies to the regular .net framework as well, but the solution is possible in .net core.

You can get hold of the parameter's custom attributes inside the `IModelBinder.BindModelAsync` method like this:

```cs
var metadata = bindingContext.ModelMetadata as DefaultModelMetadata;
var allCustomAttributes = metadata.Attributes.Attributes;
```

Where `DefaultModelMetadata` is a class and you can [read about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.defaultmodelmetadata?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Next, checking the presence of a specific custom attribute is trivial:

```cs
//check whether the custom attribute is applied to the parameter.
var myCustomAttributeIsApplied = allCustomAttributes.Any(a => a is MyCustomAttribute);
//or, get the custom attribute and do something with it.
var myCustompropertyValue = (allCustomAttributes.First(a => a is MyCustomAttribute) as MyCustomAttribute).MyCustomProperty;
```