# asp.net MVC3: Trimming all HTTP POST data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, whitespace, trim

I need to do trim to all HTTP POST data submitted by users through web forms. Having done googling, apparently there is no in-built functionality in asp.net to trim all HTTP POST data.

The closest that I can get is what is described here: [ASP.NET MVC: Best way to trim strings after data entry.  Should I create a custom model binder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custom)

Unfortunately it doesn't work on nested ViewModels (ViewModel with property with type of other ViewModel).

What is the best way to achieve this? I don't want to do property.Trim() on every properties in all ViewModel. Thank you.

Comment: Custom model binder is the way to go. Why does it not work with nested view models? You should be able to implement that.

Comment: Looking at the code again I just found out that some of the values are obtained directly from Request.Form ... that's why it doesn't work for some properties. I would consider this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define your own [`IValueProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ivalueprovider.aspx). I would start by inheriting from [`NameValueCollectionValueProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.namevaluecollectionvalueprovider.aspx) to make a `TrimmedNameValueCollectionValueProvider` in which you trim the results as you pull them out. Then you would defined a `TrimmedFormValueProvider` that passes in `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form` as the `collection`.