# view model validation that ignores leading and trailing spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following view model.

```
public UserViewModel {
 ...
 [Email(@"^.+@[^\.].*\.[a-z]{2,}$", false, ErrorMessage="...")]
 public string EmailAddress{ get; set; }
 ...
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Visitor(UserViewModel userViewModel)
...
```

However I have found that sometimes a user copies and pastes an email into the view from another email, word document etc and sometimes it picks up a leading and/or trailing space. As users are not the most intelligent and spaces do not show in the input control then really I should ignore these and carry on.

So if my model state is invalid, I am wondering the best approach to resolve this-

1. Add spaces to my validation expression.
2. In the action result method check if trim the email and remove the error from the modelstate manually.
3. Do something else...

I am not 100% sure about 1, nor 2 too be honest!

Comment: I really would not add spaces to your validation expression. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to trim strings after data entry. Should I create a custom model binder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custom-model-binder)

Answer (score 1):

you can change the setters to have the trim code upon setting the value in the property too.

Comment: Simple and easy! I like that too!

Comment: I don't. It violates [POLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), because you put one thing in and get another out.