# How to Trim() all inputs by Model in c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I found all value passed by Model is not trimmed in ASP.net MVC3

Is there a way to:

1. Apply a trim() on every field in Model (all string fields, at least; but all form fields are string before processed by Model, so better trim them all)
2. Must before `ModelState.IsValid()` (because I often found code stucked at weird `ModelState.IsValid` and later found because the form item did not be trimmed.)

Thanks.

Comment: See solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom model binder to trim any model property that is a string.

References:
[Custom model binding using IModelBinder in ASP.NET MVC](http://ivanz.com/2010/11/03/custom-model-binding-using-imodelbinder-in-asp-net-mvc-two-gotchas/)
[Iterating on an ASP.NET MVC Model Binder](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/05/05/iterating-on-an-asp-net-mvc-model-binder.aspx)
[6 Tips for ASP.NET MVC Model Binding](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx)
[A Better Model Binder](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/03/18/a-better-model-binder/)

Basically, you can take one of two approaches:

1. Implement the `IModelBinder` interface
2. Subclass the `DefaultModelBinder` class

### Example

```
public class StringTrimmingBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // trim your string here and act accordingly

        // in the case the model property isn't a string
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, I will go search what is "custom model binder" now. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Thanks for the link, reading....

Comment: Hi Mr Shark, could you please give me some working code, I do not really understand after read. I can do the trim part myself, but how to bind my code to a model, I do not have a clue. I don't even know where to put the code.

Comment: To everyone after me: remember put this in `Global.asax` `Application_Start()` `ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new whatsoeverbinder();`

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, I also wrote a small JQuery Plug_in for my project to use trim(), startsWith() & endsWith() for all the inputs string from client side.

```
(function ($) {

    String.prototype.trim = function ()
    { return (this.replace(/^[\s\xA0]+/, "").replace(/[\s\xA0]+$/, "")) };

    String.prototype.startsWith = function (str)
    { return (this.match("^" + str) == str) };

    String.prototype.endsWith = function (str)
    { return (this.match(str + "$") == str) };     

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It's a good idea to trim() on client site as well. Thanks for the code

Comment: .auto_trim as user types: http://jsfiddle.net/f3vpyhnk/73/