# Using a custom model binder for HTML strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am attempting to bind a user-inputted HTML string from a POST into a simple string variable on a model object. This works fine if I use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute. However, I'd like to sanitize the HTML before it makes its way into the model so I have created a ModelBinder:

```
public class SafeHtmlModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerCtx, ModelBindingContext bindingCtx)
    {
        var bound = base.BindModel(controllerCtx, bindingCtx);
        // TODO - return a safe HTML fragment string
        return bound;
    }
}
```

And also a `CustomModelBinderAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class SafeHtmlModelBinderAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public SafeHtmlModelBinderAttribute()
    {
        binder = new SafeHtmlModelBinder();
    }

    private IModelBinder binder;

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return binder;
    }
}
```

I then annotate the model properties which I want to be sanitized with the new attribute:

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "You must fill in your profile summary")]
[AllowHtml, SafeHtmlModelBinder, WordCount(Min = 1, Max = 300)]
public string Summary { get; set; }
```

This is following the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work! If I place a breakpoint in my `BindModel` method it is never hit. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Based on the information from Joel I have changed my IModelBinder to intercept the value when in the `SetProperty` method and instead apply the `SafeHtmlModelBinderAttribute` to the class containing string properties that can contain HTML. The code checks that the property is a string and is also allowed to contain HTML before trying to sanitize:

```
public class SafeHtmlModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void SetProperty(
        ControllerContext controllerCtx,
        ModelBindingContext bindingCtx,
        PropertyDescriptor property,
        object value)
    {
        var propertyIsString = property.PropertyType == typeof(string);
        var propertyAllowsHtml = property.Attributes.OfType<AllowHtmlAttribute>().Count() >= 1;

        var input = value as string;
        if (propertyIsString && propertyAllowsHtml && input != null)
        {
            // TODO - sanitize HTML
            value = input;
        }

        base.SetProperty(controllerCtx, bindingCtx, property, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do CustomModelBinderAttribute work on properties? Looking at the MVC source code that attribute is only used on `internal const AttributeTargets ValidTargets = AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Struct;` ...which suggests to me the framework may not expect to see this on properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just been struggling with the same thing. It seems like the GetBinder() method is never called. After digging around I found [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1774758.aspx/1) where the accepted answer is that its not possible to put a model binding attribute for a property.

Whether that's true or not I don't know but for now I'm just going to try and achieve what I need to do a different way. One idea would be to create a more generic ModelBinder and check for the presence of your attribute when performing the binding, similar to what's being suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180146).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following solution derrived from
http://aboutcode.net/2011/03/12/mvc-property-binder.html
works quite well

First you need a simple attribute that you can apply to properties

```
    public class PropertyBinderAttribute : Attribute
        {
            public PropertyBinderAttribute(Type binderType)
            {
                BinderType = binderType;
            }

            public Type BinderType { get; private set; }
        }
```

The following model binder

```
public class DefaultModelBinder : System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            var propertyBinderAttribute = TryFindPropertyBinderAttribute(propertyDescriptor);
            if (propertyBinderAttribute != null)
            {
                var binder = CreateBinder(propertyBinderAttribute);
                binder.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
            }
            else // revert to the default behavior.
            {
                base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
            }
        }

        IPropertyBinder CreateBinder(PropertyBinderAttribute propertyBinderAttribute)
        {
            return (IPropertyBinder)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(propertyBinderAttribute.BinderType);
        }

        PropertyBinderAttribute TryFindPropertyBinderAttribute(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            return propertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<PropertyBinderAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

is then overriden in Global.asax.cs

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new DefaultModelBinder();
```

then create your model binder

```
public class InvariantCultureDecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder, IPropertyBinder
    {
        public void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
        {
            var subPropertyName = CreateSubPropertyName(bindingContext.ModelName, propertyDescriptor.Name);
            if (!bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(subPropertyName))
                return;

            var attemptedValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(subPropertyName).AttemptedValue;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(attemptedValue))
                return;

            object actualValue = null;
            try
            {
                actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(attemptedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState[propertyDescriptor.Name].Errors.Add(e);
            }

            propertyDescriptor.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, actualValue);
        }

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
            object actualValue = null;
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
                    actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
            return actualValue;
        }

        //Duplicate code exits in DefaulModelBinder but it is protected internal
        private string CreateSubPropertyName(string prefix, string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
                return propertyName;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                return prefix;
            else
                return prefix + "." + propertyName;
        }

    }
```

which can now cleanly be applied in a standard way on model properties

```
[PropertyBinder(typeof(InvariantCultureDecimalModelBinder))]
public decimal? value
```

or using the built-in attribute on parameters

```
public ActionResult DoSomething([ModelBinder(typeof(InvariantCultureDecimalModelBinder))] decimal value)
```