# Trim Strings On Entity Framework Save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reflection, code-first

I'm using Entity Framework Code First within an ASP.NET MVC web application where the customers have a bad habit to add white space at the end of strings.

Obviously `Trim()` is the correct answer to fix the problem, but remembering to trim everything throughout the project isn't the right thing to do. Did some digging around and found [ASP.NET MVC: Best way to trim strings after data entry.  Should I create a custom model binder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/) where they created a custom model binder, but I'm worried there will be a performance hit on each page load of the application when the model is binded. Seems like trimming as `SaveChanges()` is called would be the most performant way to do it since things would be stored trimmed into the database.

So my question, is overriding `SaveChanges()` and getting all the added and modified objects from the `ObjectContext` then using reflection to trim every string the right thing to do here? Or is the model binder the correct way to go?

Comment: Well I would go for Custom Model Binder if you really want to do this everywhere. But I'm not sure that trimming is absolutely needed for every field... Many times, you just don't mind, do you ? If you don't mind, just Trim() where it's needed, not everywhere. For the performance hit, I think you'll have other performance problems before being stuck by this one...

Comment: Custom Model Binder seems to be the accepted way to do it. Also, if you did want to be more selective, instead of overriding SaveChanges() you could hook into the [SavingChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event as an alternative.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus There are more than a few times that matter, due to the way the data is being displayed to the user. Just trying to fix things the right way, instead of creating a patchwork of Trim's everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are worrying about performance too much. The model binder is fine we do that exact thing over our entire application.

MVC Framework is pretty big, an extra model binder isn't a lot of overhead.

Also we found cases where we had to prevent trim. Therefore model binder was perfect as it allowed us to exclude certain fields.

Model binder is standard MVC behavior. If you do it at the DB level its hidden.

So if it was me I would do it in the ModelBinder.