# How to trim spaces of model in ASP.NET Web API using ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, modelbinders, custom-model-binder

I can able to find lot of related answers to trim extra spaces in model input in ASP.NET MVC API.

Referred below links,

1. [How to trim spaces of model in ASP.NET MVC Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834600/how-to-trim-spaces-of-model-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api)
2. [Best way to trim strings after data entry. Should I create a custom model binder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custom-model-binder)

Posts are says that by implementing the IModelBinder method below we can achieve  string values trim.

```
bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext);
```

But the answers provided in the above links are with below signature.

```
object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
```

And I hope this is for MVC. Its not working for me in WEB API.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: MVC != Web api they are different things that work in subtly different ways

Comment: @Liam, Does IModelBinder has different sets of features for web api and mvc?

Comment: That's why the signatures don't match

Comment: @Liam, do you have any idea about how this can be done in Web Api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a custom model binder using the BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910346/mvc-4-modelbinder)