# Removing Whitespace from Form Submission

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

When a user fill out my form to create a new Person, I'd like there to be no whitespace before or after a name (type `String`).

`Good`: "John Doe"

`Bad`: "John Doe " or " John Doe"

Looking at this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custo), it seems that I want to use a custom ModelBinder. However, as I perhaps incorrectly understand the post, replacing my DefaultModelBinder will mean that all strings will not be allowed to have leading or trailing whitespace.

How can I ensure that only `Name`'s are affected by this custom ModelBinder?

Comment: The point of that linked SO question was to not explicitly Trim() every string so I guess thats the case here too. I wonder if using such a sophisticated way for only one field is a good idea though.

Comment: A model binding solution sounds like overkill to me.

Comment: @S_F, since the other post is searching by type String, how isn't  every string getting trimmed? Hi Adrian - thanks for pointing out the overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write this behaviour straight into your view-model (if you're using view-models):

```
private string name;

public string Name
{
    get { return this.name; }

    set { this.name = value.Trim(); }
}
```

Then the `Name` will arrive pre-trimmed in your controller action method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Boe Title (typo?), however it may be better to add a similar bit of code into your domain/application entity instead (or as well as).  I'd avoid adding any logic like this into your DB queries or stored procedures though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) function. 
From MSDN,

> The Trim method removes from the current string all leading and trailing white-space characters.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'm still figuring out the right place to put the `Trim()`

Comment: @Kevin Doesn't your form(dialog?) have a 'Ok" button for user to submit what they fill? I think you just need to post-process their name when they actually press 'ok' or whatever button that makes close your form.

Answer (score 0):

You can have have name mentioned in property for ex:

```
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
```

And then you can use the modified code below for the Custom Model binder solution in the post you have mentioned:

```
public class TrimModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                        ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
                                        System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.Name.ToUpper().Contains("NAME")
             && (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            var stringValue = (string) value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
                stringValue = stringValue.Trim();

            value = stringValue;
        }

        base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext,
                         propertyDescriptor, value);
    }
}
```

This way any name property that name in it and is type of string will have the white spaces trimmed as you want here.