# Trim all user input strings in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am looking for a way to trim all user input in ASP.NET without calling [Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) on every string instance.  I came across [extending the DefaultModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custo?rq=1) for MVC.  Is there a way to do this in web forms?  What options are available?  As a less desirable option, is there a way to incorporate this into the set method of a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the utility method to trim all TextBoxes in a page (or a parent control) recursively.

```
public static void TrimTextBoxesRecursive(Control root)
{
    foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            var textbox = control as TextBox;
            textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            TrimTextBoxesRecursive(control);
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TrimTextBoxesRecursive(Page);
}
```

Comment: This was the perfect solution for my current need.  Quick implementation and didn't require changing all of controls in my existing project.  I had a large page so I just replaced the control parameter with the nested panel of the controls I needed trimmed.

Answer (score 8):

You could create a custom `TextBox` which always returns a trimmed version of the text:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text.Trim(); }
        set { base.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Then just use this instead of the normal `TextBox` anywhere you need this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call this extension method from the appropriate parent, e.g. Page.TrimTextControls

```
public static void TrimTextControls(this Control parent, bool TrimLeading)
{
  foreach (TextBox txt in parent.GetAllControls().OfType<TextBox>())
  {
    if (TrimLeading)
    {
      txt.Text = txt.Text.Trim();
    }
    else
    {
      txt.Text = txt.Text.TrimEnd();
    }
  }
}
```