# Any way to search through a whole HTML Form? Or restrict characters globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a database that cannot accept non 8-bit chars, and if the user adds a Euro symbol throughout the form the whole thing collapses.

It's a very, very big form and I don't really want to add lines of code everywhere to run a simple replace function - but I can't find any method online to search through a whole form pre-submit, is this possible?

Failing that what's the best way to restrict certain character inputs globally in my web form?

Running ASP.NET MVC4 using lots of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not enough info to answer this as best as possible. But I will give it a go. You wouldn't add lines of code everywhere. I assume you are aggregating the form data before submission, at that point you would strip the euro symbol. Assume it is an object..

```
var formObj = {firstName : "aspiring€", lastName : "programmer€", comment : "I really like euro symbols!!€€€!!" }

$.each(formObj, function( key, value ) {
  formObj[key] = formObj[key].replace(/€/g, '');
});

console.log(formObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 possible options

A. Your could create a custom model binder that strips the invalid characters before the model is bound. [Refer this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718501/asp-net-mvc-best-way-to-trim-strings-after-data-entry-should-i-create-a-custo) for a custom model binder that removes white space from posted values. The advantage is that you can register it in `global.asax.cs` and your model properties will not contain invalid characters on post back. The disadvantage is that if `ModelState` is not valid and you return the view, then the user sees the modified text, which might be confusing (*what happened to what I entered?*)

B. Create an attribute that inherits from `RegularExpressionAttribute` and apply it to all relevant properties

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public MyAttribute() : base(@"^[^\u20AC]+$")
    {
        // Add default error message
        ErrorMessage = "The value cannot contain the euro symbol";
    }
}
```

and register it in `Global.asax.cs`

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MyAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

The advantage is that it gives both client side and server validation. The disadvantage is that you need to remember to add it to all properties