# Pass JWT Token from Body to Header

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

I followed this thread: [Authentication & Authorization - Token in HTTP request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393369/authentication-authorization-token-in-http-request-body) to pass the authentication token from the body to the header:

```
OnMessageReceived = ctx => {
    ctx.Request.EnableBuffering();

    //var test = ctx.Request.Method;
    //var test2 = ctx.Request.Body;

    //var bodyAsText = new System.IO.StreamReader(ctx.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
    //var body2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(bodyAsText);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ctx.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
        var jsonBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

        /* var keyValueParis = jsonBody.Split('&')
            .Select(value => value.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(pair => Uri.UnescapeDataString(pair[0]), pair => Uri.UnescapeDataString(pair[1])); */

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };
        //var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JwtSerialization>(bodyAsText);

        var body = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonBody, options);
        ctx.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        if (body != null)
        {
            ctx.Token = body.Token;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(jsonBody);
        ctx.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

But when I do it that way I receive the error:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Text.Json.JsonException
>
> An exception of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' occurred in System.Text.Json.dll but was not handled in user code: ''A' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.'

The body I am passing with PowerShell looks like that:

```
$body:                                                           
Name                           Value                                          
----                           -----
Authorization                  Bearer eyJ1fXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1…
Content-Type                   application/json
```

I also tried to pass a class to the Deserialize method instead of dynamic:

```
public class JwtSerialization
{
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

But honestly, I am not even sure which type of class I have to pass.

Update:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(ctx.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
                    {
                        
                        var jsonBody = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonBody) == false){
                            var keyValueParis = jsonBody.Split('&')
                                .Select(value => value.Split('='))
                                .ToDictionary(pair => Uri.UnescapeDataString(pair[0]), pair => Uri.UnescapeDataString(pair[1]));

                            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyValueParis["Authorization"]) == false){
                                
                                var token = keyValueParis["Authorization"].Replace("Bearer", "").Replace("+", "");

                                if(new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\.?[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*$").IsMatch(token ?? String.Empty)){
                                
                                    //var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
                                    //{
                                    //    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
                                    //};
                                    //var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(keyValueParis, options);
                                    //var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(jsonString, options);
                                    //var data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JwtSerialization>(bodyAsText);

                                    //var body = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonBody, options);
                                    ctx.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                                    ctx.Token = token;
                                    
                                    ctx.Request.Body.Position = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Authorization and Content-Type passed in body?

Comment: Yes. Reason is that I have to reuse the same header twice. Once for the application proxy authentication and later on for the local IIS authentication. I am requesting a JWT token from an azure app, that is valid for the Entra ID authentication and then has to be used for the asp.net core app.

Comment: Based on your error, Firstly, ensure that the JSON being sent in the request body is correctly formatted. From the PowerShell snippet you provided, it seems like the JSON is being sent correctly.

Next, let's check how you're deserializing the JSON in the middleware. You're using JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonBody, options) to deserialize the JSON into a dynamic object. This can sometimes be error-prone, especially if the structure of the JSON is not known beforehand. You can try this `context.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {body.AccessToken}";`

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron,
you are right, the JSON parsing is not working "automatically" like it does in PowerShell. So I just used Replace to get the token. If there is a better option as updated in the initial post please correct me

Comment: Accordingly to your scenario, you could extract the token from the body by the key of token. I think that will be alright.

Comment: You could simply try `var body = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JwtSerialization>(jsonBody, options);` then get your token form the body using `body.AccessToken`