# How to replace value of properties that have a specific attribute in a middleware .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class IgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

I want to add this attribute to some classes or properties to replace the value of that property or class with something like `null` or `default()` in a middleware.
Like this

```
public class Login
{
    [Ignore]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Based on
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2282254/9995067
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500627/9995067
If I want to check the properties that have that specific attribute I need to know the type of the object and in the middleware I have access to HttpContext request and response body.
The Request and Response model can be anything. How can I handle that?

Comment: Have you done any research at all? For example, do you know that if you reflect over a type, get the type's properties, and then use `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` to find the attributes associated with those properties.  By the way, if you are planning to do something like this, you probably want to limit the use of your `Ignore` attribute, changing it's `AttributeTarget` from `All`

Comment: @Flydog57 Thank you for the comment. this attribute can be used on a class or interface as well. on the other hand, I have a Logging middleware that logs the httpcontext request and response body and that is the place I want to change the values.

Comment: Then you can OR the values together

Comment: Re: "The Request and Response model can be anything. How can I handle that?"  If you have an object, it has a type.  You can get the type by calling `object.GetType()`.  Once you have the type, you have the key to reflection

Comment: [Write custom ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-6.0)